# tree traverse recursive in level-first order and depth-first order

Tags: algorithm, tree, traversal

Is there any algorithm can traverse a tree recursively in level-first order and non-recursively in postorder.Thanks a lot.

Comment: no, last night I took part in paper test of one company.

Comment: By level-first, you mean breadth-first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an effectively recursive breadth-first search you can use [iterative deepening depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search). It's particularly good for situations where the branching factor is high, where regular breadth-first search tends to choke from excessive memory consumption.

**Edit:** [Marcos Marin already mentioned it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569972/tree-traverse-recursive-in-level-first-order-and-depth-first-order/1570117#1570117), but for the sake of completeness, [the Wikipedia page on breadth-first traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_traversal) describes the algorithm thus:

> 1. Enqueue the root node.
> 2. Dequeue a node and examine it.
>
>    - If the element sought is found in this node, quit the search and return a result.
>    - Otherwise enqueue any successors (the direct child nodes) that have not yet been discovered.
> 3. If the queue is empty, every node on the graph has been examined – quit the search and return "not found".
> 4. Repeat from Step 2.
>
> **Note**: Using a stack instead of a queue would turn this algorithm into a depth-first search.

That last line is, obviously, interesting to you if you want to do a non-recursive depth-first traversal. Getting pre- or post-order is just a matter of modifying how you append the nodes in step 2.b.

Answer (score 1):

You can recurse a tree in post order iteratively by using a stack instead of the implicit call stack used in recursion.

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) says,

> **Traversal**
>
> Compared to linear data structures
> like linked lists and one dimensional
> arrays, which have only one logical
> means of traversal, tree structures
> can be traversed in many different
> ways. Starting at the root of a binary
> tree, there are three main steps that
> can be performed and the order in
> which they are performed defines the
> traversal type.
>
> These steps (in no
> particular order) are: performing an
> action on the current node (referred
> to as "visiting" the node), traversing
> to the left child node, and traversing
> to the right child node. Thus the
> process is most easily described
> through recursion.
>
> To traverse a non-empty binary tree in
> preorder, perform the following
> operations recursively at each node,
> starting with the root node:
>
> 1. Visit the node.
> 2. Traverse the left subtree.
> 3. Traverse the right subtree. (This is also called **[Depth-first
>    traversal.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)**)
>
> To traverse a non-empty binary tree in
> inorder, perform the following
> operations recursively at each node:
>
> 1. Traverse the left subtree.
> 2. Visit the node.
> 3. Traverse the right subtree. (This is also called Symmetric traversal.)
>
> To traverse a non-empty binary tree in
> postorder, perform the following
> operations recursively at each node:
>
> 1. Traverse the left subtree.
> 2. Traverse the right subtree.
> 3. Visit the node.
>
> Finally, trees can also be traversed
> in **level-order**, where we visit every
> node on a level before going to a
> lower level. This is also called
> **[Breadth-first traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_traversal)**.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question, your postorder traversal is recursive and you didn't post a non-recursive solution for the breadth-first traversal.